# MS Access Query (two tables only)

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have two tables:

```
**T1**
ID |Transaction| amount |
1  |trans1     | 97     |
1  |trans2     | 22     |
2  |trans7     | 98     |


**T2** 
ID |description|spec|
1  |Item 1     |text|
2  |Item 2     |zip |
```

Note: ID columns in both tables are THE SAME. However, ID in table T1 is not unique.

I need query to retrieve data from tables but only row with highest amount (table T1). Example result:

```
ID|description|spec|transaction|amount|
1 |item1      |text| trans1    |  97  | 
2 |item2      |zip | trans7    |  98  |
```

Please **help**!

Thank you.

Comment: Your example result isn't right, is it?  It shows both records have ID = 1.

Comment: ye also it shows a mix row from T1, i.e. trans2,97

Comment: Oh sorry about that guys; 2AM here ... Appreciate your attention to details...

Answer (score 1):

You should use this query to get one row for each ID in the T2

```
SELECT ID, MAX(AMOUNT) AS AMT FROM T1 GROUP BY ID
```

Then join the first table into it and select all that you need. So it would look like something like this:

```
SELECT T2.ID,
  description,
  spec,
  transaction ,
  AMT
FROM T2
JOIN
  (SELECT ID, MAX(AMOUNT) AS AMT FROM T1 GROUP BY ID
  ) T3
ON T3.ID=T2.ID;
```

Note: I used Oracle, in your db you might need to modify the query in order to resolve keyword conflicts.

Comment: It doesn't work; can't find a field transaction. I see how you get all columns but really how to get transaction or any other columns from T1 that I haven't included in my example. Any idea Ali? Thanks!

Comment: Since the field `transaction` doesn't appear in T2 Or T3, you'll need to modify this further.

Comment: If you want to get more columns on the T1 you should add them to the first sql statement above. i.e. SELECT ID, MAX(AMOUNT) AS AMT, column2, column3, ..... FROM T1 GROUP BY ID

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT ID, description, spec, `transaction` , amt
FROM T2
JOIN
  (SELECT ID, `transaction`, MAX(amount) AS amt FROM T1 GROUP BY ID) AS T3
ON T3.ID=T2.ID
```

watch out, because the word `transaction` may be a reserved keyword.  You could always enclose in tick marks (like above)

Comment: This doesn't seems to be correct. This query would throw an error: SELECT ID, MAX(amount) as amt FROM T1

Comment: Yes, okay, added a `GROUP BY` clause.